# How do I install Wordpress with ftp?

Tags: wordpress

I installed wordpress with Nginx using this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-20-04
successfully. But now I need to import my website export file, which is bigger than 2 MB, so I need to do it via ftp. How do configure ftp in wp-admin.php in order to import data? Do i have to configure sftp or ftp on that server?

Is there not an easy way?

Comment: What is the data you want to import? What you want to say is the WordPress attachment file import? So do you want to add a file in `wp-content/uploads`?

Comment: export my website and import it again

Comment: You can use [plugins like this](https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/). "SQL, Media, Other Files" for you can zip and export files and restore them again.